# firebase dynamic link is not working "admin.dynamicLinks is not a function"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm working on a Node js project and I have to use Firebase dynamic link..

But whenever I try to get the dynamicLink function from firebase admin I get this error: `admin.dynamicLinks is not a function`

I downloaded firebase-admin package `"firebase-admin": "^11.6.0",` package and I configured it in this way:

```
import serviceAccount from "./myConfig.mjs";

// FIREBASE CONFIG
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.APIKEYFIREBASE,
  appId: process.env.APPID,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECTID,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTHDOMAIN,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGEBUCKET,
  measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENTID,
};

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

initializeApp({ credential: firebaseConfig });

const app = express();
```

I didn't configure firebase dynamic link with firebase admin, I don't know if it makes the issue.

I can get many of firebase functions but not all of them, for example I can get `apps, auth, storage, database, firestore` by writing `admin.storage(), admin.database() ...` but I don't know why I can't access to Dynamic Link..

Here is version of package and libraries :

Node js : v16.14.2
firebase-admin : ^11.6.0
firebase-dynamic-links : ^1.2.0

I downloaded `firebase-dynamic-links` npm package and created many dynamic links with it, but I think there is no way to updated dynamic link in this package..

here is firebase-dynamic-link configuration :

```
import { FirebaseDynamicLinks } from "firebase-dynamic-links";
const firebaseDynamicLinks = new FirebaseDynamicLinks(
  TOKEN
);

const createDynamicLink = () => {
     const destinationUrl = `https://www.google.com`;

     const { shortLink, previewLink } = await firebaseDynamicLinks.createLink({
       dynamicLinkInfo: {
        domainUriPrefix: "mydomain.page.link",
         link: destinationUrl,
         androidInfo: {
           androidPackageName: "com.company.package",
           androidFallbackLink: destinationUrl,
         },
         iosInfo: {
           iosBundleId: "package.newsapp",
           iosFallbackLink: destinationUrl,
         },
       },
     });
}
```

Please help me to if I have wrongly configured the firebase with Node js or provide me the code to update dynamic link using the `firebase-dynamic-links npm package`